# Question about n channel mosfet as a switch(simulink/ simscape electrical)

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, bridge-rectifier, simulink

i have to implement the following circuit which is an energy harvester circuit using simscape electrical. The description of the circuit is this one found on page 7 of the pdf at [Finite element-based assessment of energy harvesting in composite beams with piezoelectric transducers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355404949_Finite_element-based_assessment_of_energy_harvesting_in_composite_beams_with_piezoelectric_transducers):

> [image]
>
> **Figure 5.** In-house harvesting circuit (cc-ih): (b) systems modeling approach.
>
> The in-house circuit (Figure 5) consists of a diode rectifier
> due to the alternating input current, a capacitor which is
> charged by the rectified electric current and a load with
> a MOSFET switch which discharges the capacitor.
> The in-house circuit is designed as simple as possible
> because its main purposes are model validation and
> design exploration. As shown in Figure 5, the circuit consists of a diode rectifier – due to alternating current from
> the oscillating PE transducer – in parallel with a capacitor
> which accumulates charge. The current provided by the
> PE transducer component is independent of the electric
> circuit. A MOSFET acts as a load switch. When it does
> not conduct, the capacitor is charged, else it is discharged
> providing current to the resistive load. Selecting properly
> the capacitor capacitance and upper and lower voltage
> thresholds, different types of loads including batteries
> can be powered.

[image]
the threshold voltage for the mosfet to conduct or not is 2.4 voltage. i am trying to use a comparator block to implement the controller but i cant connect the output of the voltage sensor to the input of the comparator . do you have any idea why that is happening. everything is from simscape electrical library and it should be working

Comment: Since the question is about ``an energy harvester circuit``, how efficient does it need to be? [Energy harvesting using piezoelectric transducers for suspension systems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957415819301266#sec0009) shows an example of a PE transducer producing a voltage of up to +/-5 V at +/- 50 uA so a bridge rectifier could waste a significant amount of the harvested energy for that example. What voltage and current does your PE transducer generate?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i ve added the full paper at the end of the post, but i dont think thats my problem right now. my question has to do with the control logic that i must implement and i think i am missing something. i ve added a voltage sensor at the capacitor so i can monitor its voltage and then i have tried different things and it still doesnt work, either with using a comparator to connect its output to the mosfet gate, or with relational operators and constans( using the threshold voltages where the mosfet turns off/on). so my question is if you have any  idea for the control logic

Comment: I'm not a user of simscape electrical, but can you clarify what ``try to connect the output of the control logic I made to the gate of the mosfet it wouldn't let me`` means. Do you get an error from simscape electrical?

Comment: "It wouldn't let me"? What specifically was the problem (I'm assuming that nothing physically prevented you from doing this). And, why not show your version of the circuit in case you introduced an error?